# create radio button from code behind but with an onclick?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I had a table in front end...

```
<table>
<tr>
<td style="padding-right:8px">
<input id="mmapMS" type="radio" name="Layers" value="mmapMS" onclick="addLayer()" style="display:none"/>
<label class="Layer-cc mMS" for="mMS" data-tip="mMS"></label>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Need to change the radio button to run from the back end...all good so far (below) but I cant find out how to call a js function when I click the radio button??...onclick="addLayer()" any ideas...thanks

```
                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();

                HtmlInputRadioButton btn = new HtmlInputRadioButton();
                btn.ID = mapGenieImage;
                btn.Value = mapGenieImage;
                btn.Visible = false;
                cell.Controls.Add(btn);

                Label lb = new Label();   
                lb.CssClass = "Layer-cc " + mapImage;
                cell.Controls.Add(lb);

                row.Cells.Add(cell);
                table.Rows.Add(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlInputRadioButton btn = new HtmlInputRadioButton();
btn.ID = mapGenieImage;
btn.Value = mapGenieImage;
btn.Visible = false;
btn.attributes.add("onclick","addLayer()")  '<-- Add me.
cell.Controls.Add(btn);
```

When creating your control, add an attribute of onClick which calls your addLayer() script.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to this question! Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow, because it can be difficult for the original poster (or future readers) to understand the logic behind them. Please, edit your question and include an explanation of your code so that others can benefit from your answer. Thanks!